# My code to move in unity 2D game not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 
public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float runSpeed = 10f;
    Vector2 moveInput;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Run();
    }
 
    void OnMove(InputValue value){
        moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log(moveInput);
    }
 
    void Run()
    {
        Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * runSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y);
        rigidbody.velocity = moveInput;
    }
}
```

But my character still mowing with speed of 2f and can fly up and down (i did it in first version of my code).

It looks like game not loaded newest code and don't know how to fix it.

I have selected auto refresh.

Comment: Your inspector has a 1 in that field, because that was the default value when it was created. You haven't changed the inspector value and you havent reset the object so why would it change? Consider changing the value in the inspector or making it not serialized if the inspector is not meant to control the runspeed value. See this question for more info: [Why is Unity ignoring the initialized value of a non-static public field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744405/why-is-unity-ignoring-the-initialized-value-of-a-non-static-public-field)

Comment: But my character still cant fly, but shouldn't (this value is not serialized)

Comment: Why wouldnt it be able to fly? You're assigning the input to velocity with the line `rigidbody.velocity = moveInput;`. Did you mean to do something with the local `playerVelocity` variable?

Comment: Yay, thanks, i forgot to assign value, im dumb (sorry, 22pm there) Thanks!